# Finding Last n Groups of Rows in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (1m+ rows) that contains test data. A snapshot of "Events" was taken at various times and up to three rows were added to the dataframe per snapshot. Eg, in the extract below the first snapshot for Event At223 was taken at 18/03/2016  18:10:45, the second at 21/03/2016  10:14:28, etc.

I want to filter the dataframe so that it returns only the last n snapshots per Ref. Refs are unique whereas Events may be duplicated.

I'm new to Pandas but have tried various combinations of sort_values, groupby and tail but cannot get the desired result. Eg:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Ref', 'Time']).groupby(['Time', 'Ref', 'TestId']).tail(3)
```

Can anyone suggest how to do it? In the deisred result example below n = 3 so it shows the last three snapshots per Ref.

Extract:

| Time | Ref | Event | EndTime | TestId | TestNames | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/03/2016 18:10:45 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 18/03/2016 18:10:45 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two |  |
| 18/03/2016 18:10:45 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 21/03/2016 10:14:28 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 21/03/2016 10:14:28 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4 |
| 21/03/2016 10:14:28 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 21/03/2016 12:44:34 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 21/03/2016 12:44:34 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 21/03/2016 12:44:34 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:05:16 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:05:16 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 21/03/2016 13:05:16 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:14:22 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:14:22 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 21/03/2016 13:14:22 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 01/04/2016 10:37:43 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 01/04/2016 10:37:43 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 01/04/2016 10:37:43 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 18/03/2016 18:12:12 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7 |
| 18/03/2016 18:12:12 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.58 |
| 18/03/2016 18:12:12 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.4 |
| 21/03/2016 13:03:48 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7.2 |
| 21/03/2016 13:03:48 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.58 |
| 21/03/2016 13:03:48 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.4 |
| 21/03/2016 13:19:15 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7.2 |
| 21/03/2016 13:19:15 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.58 |
| 21/03/2016 13:19:15 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.5 |
| 01/04/2016 12:48:13 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7.2 |
| 01/04/2016 12:48:13 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.59 |
| 01/04/2016 12:48:13 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.5 |

Desired result:

| Time | Ref | Event | EndTime | TestId | TestNames | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21/03/2016 13:05:16 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:05:16 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 21/03/2016 13:05:16 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:14:22 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:14:22 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 21/03/2016 13:14:22 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 01/04/2016 10:37:43 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 28212 | One |  |
| 01/04/2016 10:37:43 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 466299 | Two | 4.5 |
| 01/04/2016 10:37:43 | 1.123717985 | At223 | 01/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Three |  |
| 21/03/2016 13:03:48 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7.2 |
| 21/03/2016 13:03:48 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.58 |
| 21/03/2016 13:03:48 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.4 |
| 21/03/2016 13:19:15 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7.2 |
| 21/03/2016 13:19:15 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.58 |
| 21/03/2016 13:19:15 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.5 |
| 01/04/2016 12:48:13 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 28214 | Eight | 7.2 |
| 01/04/2016 12:48:13 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 1212772 | Nine | 1.59 |
| 01/04/2016 12:48:13 | 1.123719512 | Br12 | 03/04/2016 16:00 | 58805 | Ten | 4.5 |

Comment: It seems there are always 3 lines per snapshot?

Comment: Why the desired output has far more than 3 entries for Ref `1.123717985`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through each unique event and grab the top n times from each. Then concatenate the results together:

```
n = 3
event_dfs = []
for event in df['Event'].unique():
   sub_df = df.loc[df['Event'] == event]
   max_times = sub_df['Time'].nlargest(n=n)
   event_dfs.append(sub_df.loc[sub_df['Time'].isin(max_times)])

result = pd.concat(event_dfs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Factorize the date and keep the n highest values (assuming your dataframe is already sorted by Time)

```
# Number of snapshot you want to keep
n = 3 

# Create a boolean mask
m = (df.assign(val=pd.factorize(df['Time'])[0])
       .groupby('Ref')['val']
       .transform(lambda x: x.max() - x < n))

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                   Time       Ref  Event           EndTime   TestId TestNames  Result
9   21/03/2016 13:05:16  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00    28212       One     NaN
10  21/03/2016 13:05:16  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00   466299       Two    4.50
11  21/03/2016 13:05:16  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00    58805     Three     NaN
12  21/03/2016 13:14:22  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00    28212       One     NaN
13  21/03/2016 13:14:22  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00   466299       Two    4.50
14  21/03/2016 13:14:22  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00    58805     Three     NaN
15  01/04/2016 10:37:43  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00    28212       One     NaN
16  01/04/2016 10:37:43  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00   466299       Two    4.50
17  01/04/2016 10:37:43  1.123718  At223  01/04/2016 16:00    58805     Three     NaN
21  21/03/2016 13:03:48  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00    28214     Eight    7.20
22  21/03/2016 13:03:48  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00  1212772      Nine    1.58
23  21/03/2016 13:03:48  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00    58805       Ten    4.40
24  21/03/2016 13:19:15  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00    28214     Eight    7.20
25  21/03/2016 13:19:15  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00  1212772      Nine    1.58
26  21/03/2016 13:19:15  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00    58805       Ten    4.50
27  01/04/2016 12:48:13  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00    28214     Eight    7.20
28  01/04/2016 12:48:13  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00  1212772      Nine    1.59
29  01/04/2016 12:48:13  1.123720   Br12  03/04/2016 16:00    58805       Ten    4.50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` after `groupby`

And create a function that only handles dataframes with a single `Ref`

```py
def extract_n_last_times(n: int):
    def extract_last_times(group: pd.DataFrame):
        times = group.sort_values("Time")["Time"].unique()
        return group[group["Time"].isin(times[-n:])]
    return extract_last_times

df.sort_values(["Ref", "Time"]).groupby("Ref", group_keys=False).apply(extract_n_last_times(n=3))
```